# c# StackOverflowException when declaring jagged arrays

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am getting a StackOverflowException when debugging my c# array declaration, which goes like this:

```
public class ConfigClass : MainWindow
{
    private const int totalIndex = 3;
    public int[][][] Config = new int[totalIndex][][]
    {
        new int[1][]
        {
            new int[] {10, 5, 5, 5, 1, 4},
        },
        new int[9][]
        {
            new int[] {4, 3, 1, 4, 2},
            new int[] {4, 8, 6, 7, 5},
            new int[] {2, 2, 4},
            new int[] {2, 2, 4},
            new int[] {0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        },
        new int[9][]
        {
            new int[] {4, 1, 2, 3, 4},
            new int[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
            new int[] {2, 2, 4},
            new int[] {2, 2, 4},
            new int[] {0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        },
    };
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ConfigClass Core = new ConfigClass();
    public DateTime systemDateTime = new DateTime();

    public static class ReferenceTo
    {
        // for group
        public const int group_A = 0;
        public const int group_B = 1;
        public const int group_C = 2;
        public const int group_D = 3;
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartSecondTimer();
    }

    public void UpdateTime()
    {
        label_systemTime.Content = systemDateTime.ToLongTimeString();
        label_systemDate.Content = systemDateTime.ToLongDateString();
    }

    public void StartSecondTimer() // start one second timebase
    {
        DispatcherTimer secondTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        secondTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherSecond_Tick);
        secondTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        secondTimer.Start();
    }

    private void dispatcherSecond_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // one second timebase event handler
    {
        systemDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        UpdateTime();
    }
}
```

It is saying I have might have infinite loop or infinite recursion. What am I missing here?

Thanks! :)

EDIT: I added the 'public class ConfigClass : MainWindow' which is the source of the error.

Comment: This runs perfectly for me. The code you've posted is not the issue

Comment: If your declaration were the issue, the code would fail to compile, not throw a run time exception.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the prompt response. I have added the declaration that causes the problem, which is 'public class ConfigClass : MainWindow'

Comment: @ExtraFries That line would not throw a stack overflow exception. It's possible your code in `MainWindow` is broken. Can you please tell us and show us the exact line that throws the exception? That is - when your debugger breaks, show us the line it's stuck on

Comment: @Rob: it breaks just before the whole `public int[][][] Config = new int[totalIndex][][]` declaration, but here's where it stuck at `MainWindow`: `ConfigClass core = new ConfigClass();`

Comment: You'll need to show us what's written in `MainWindow`

Comment: Oops, sorry for the mess. Edited code in original post. @Rob

Comment: My purpose for inheriting `MainWindow` on `ConfigClass` is because I want to use the `Reference.To` class to look things up in arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your infinite loop is because of this:

```
ConfigClass Core = new ConfigClass();
```

in your `MainWindow` class.

Every time you create a `ConfigClass`, the `MainWindow` constructor (and field initialization) will run as well. However, `MainWindow`'s field initialization includes creating another `ConfigClass`. And so *its* constructor and super classes constructor will run.

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're trying to do (it's a bit suspect to have a reference to a sub class in your `MainWindow`) - but the above is the cause of your problems.

From your comment:

> My purpose for inheriting MainWindow on ConfigClass is because I want to use the Reference.To class to look things up in arrays.

You don't need to inherit from `MainWindow` to do that. *Any* part of your code can write `MainWindow.ReferenceTo` without an issue

Comment: Thanks Rob. Makes total sense now. :)